# Pass custom function response in model popup in VF page using Angular JS?

Tags: apex, visualforce, angularjs, popup

I have created a Visualforce page and i am using Angular js in it.In Angluar js by using Javascript remoting call Apex method.Now i want to pass apex method response in model popup when click on Checkbox. I have following peace of code:

CheckAvaibility.vpf

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Lead" extensions="CheckAvailibilityLeadController" readOnly="true">
    <html lang="en-US"  ng-app="myApp" >
        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.9.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/alertifyjs/1.9.0/css/alertify.min.css"/>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!--cdn for model popup-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-controller="cont">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="myCheckBox" ng-click="checkSelect(y,finalthefinalarray[$parent.$parent.$index].dates[$parent.$index].date,finalthefinalarray[$parent.$parent.$index].Name)"  ng-disabled="((d.morningB == true && $index==0 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.lunchB == true && $index==1 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.eveningB == true && $index==2 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.dinnerB == true && $index==3 && d.BanquetName == x.Name))||((d.morningU == true && $index==0 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.lunchU == true && $index==1 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.eveningU == true && $index==2 && d.BanquetName == x.Name) || (d.dinnerU == true && $index==3 && d.BanquetName == x.Name))"/>
        </body>
        <script >
        var app1 = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
        app1.controller('cont', ['$scope','SidFactory','$window','$filter','$timeout', function($scope,SidFactory,$window,$filter,$timeout,$dialog){
        $scope.checkSelect=function(slot,slotdate,location) 
            {
                var timeslot = slot;
                var date = new Date(slotdate),
                    mnth = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
                    day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    var slotDate= [date.getFullYear(), mnth, day].join("-");
                    var place = location;
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('CheckAvailibilityLeadController.getSlotInfo', timeslot,slotDate,place,
                    function(result, event){

                    //How to pass result in model popup
                        //$dialog.dialog({}).open('test.vfp');
                    //alert(event);
                    },
                    {escape: true}
                );
            }
}]);

</script>
    </html>

</apex:page>
```

And following Apex class:

```
global class CheckAvailibilityLeadController {

@RemoteAction
global static String getSlotInfo(String timeslot,string slotDate, string place){
    Date startDate = Date.valueof(slotDate);
    return JSON.serialize([SELECT id,slot__C,Date__c,Location__r.Name,Opportunity__r.Name,slot_status__c,Priority__c FROM Banquet_Slot_Rent_Info__c WHERE slot__c=:timeslot AND Date__c=:startDate AND Location__r.Name=:place]);            
}
}
```

Where i have to write Popup page code i meant in "CheckAvaibility.vpf" or Create Seperate vf page. Please guide me i am new to this scenario.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi jsmith, you have to use the same vf page for this. After you get the response from remoting call, do all operation inside apply() function . After that call another JS function with the required values you need to show in the popup.

Comment: Hey Arabinda Thanks for your response.I did it by referring https://sarvforce.wordpress.com/2015/06/23/angular-js-modal-and-vf-page/